# Expanding url from shortened url obtained from tweet

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.x, url, pandas

I have a twitter data set. I have extracted all the expanded urls from the json and now am trying to resolve the shortened ones. Also, I need to check which urls are still working and only keep those.

I am parsing over 5 million urls. The problem is that the code below is slow. Can anyone suggest how to make it faster? Is there a better way to do this?

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from urllib2 import urlopen
import urllib2
import threading
import time



def urlResolution(url,tweetId,w):

    try:

        print "Entered Function"
        print "Original Url:",url

        hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

        #header has been added since some sites give an error otherwise
        req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)
        temp = urlopen(req)
        newUrl = temp.geturl()
        print "Resolved Url:",newUrl
        if newUrl!= 'None':
            print "in if condition"
            w.writerow([tweetId,newUrl])

    except Exception,e:
        print "Throwing exception"
        print str(e)
        return None


def urlResolver(urlFile):
    df=pd.read_csv(urlFile, delimiter="\t")

    df['Url']
    df2 = df[["Tweet ID","Url"]].copy()
    start = time.time()

    df3 = df2[df2.Url!="None"]

    list_url = []
    n=0
    w = csv.writer(open("OUTPUT_FILE.tsv", "w"), delimiter = '\t')
        w.writerow(["Tweet ID","Url"])

    maxC = 0
    while maxC < df3.shape[0]:
        #creates threads
        #only 40 threads are created at a time, since for large number of threads it gives <too many open files> error
        threads = [threading.Thread(target=urlResolution, args=(df3.iloc[n]['Url'],df3.iloc[n]['Tweet ID'],w)) for n in range(maxC,maxC+40)]


        for thread in threads:
                thread.start()
        for thread in threads:
                thread.join()
        if maxC+40 >= df3.shape[0]:
            threads = [threading.Thread(target=urlResolution, args=(df3.iloc[n]['Url'],df3.iloc[n]['Tweet ID'],w)) for n in range(maxC,df3.shape[0])]

                    print "threads complete"
                    for thread in threads:
                            thread.start()
                    for thread in threads:
                            thread.join()   
            break
        maxC = maxC + 40
    print "Elapsed Time: %s" % (time.time() - start)

    w.close()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    df3 = urlResolver("INPUT_FILE.tsv")
```

Comment: If twitter supported plain `http` connections, you could just connect to port `80` and read the `Location` header value in the`301` response, without actually loading the whole page (which is why it's actually slow). But i doubt it's supported, and even if it is, it may mean a double redirection (http -> https -> real URL). You probably don't want to implement an https call from scratch, so I'd say what you've done is the best you can get.

Answer (score 2):

Couple things I'd try:

- switch to [`requests` module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) reusing the [`requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) to let it reuse the same TCP connection:

  > ..if you're making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP
  >   connection will be reused, which can result in a significant
  >   performance increase
- use the ["HEAD" HTTP method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python-2) (in case of `requests` you may need the `allow_redirects=True`)
- try out [`Scrapy` web-scraping framework](http://scrapy.org/) which is of an [asynchronous nature](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html) and is based on the `twisted` network library. You would also move the CSV output part to an [output pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943075/scrapy-pipeline-to-export-csv-file-in-the-right-format).
- another thing to try is use the [`grequests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grequests) library (`requests` on `gevent`)

Some micro-optimization ideas:

- move the `hdr` dictionary definition to the module level to avoid redefining it every time `urlResolution()` is called (and, since it is a constant use upper-case; and pick a more readable variable name - `HEADERS`?)